# choosing a method of user to user comunication

Tags: javascript, php, web

Lets say i want to create a chat service. in my eyes there are two ways of doing things and i would like to know what you guys think is the better way to do it. or maybe ther's a third option... i don't know.

anyway

Solution 1:

Have a JavaScript loop where i send a request to the server in intervals that checks the database for any new messages that may have occurred. When i see that my database has a flag that signals hers the new line of text call another function to retrieve and display

Solution 2:

have a async call to a method on the sever that waits in a loop on the server waiting for a new entry and then when it gets there send the response to the client.

i have no idea witch one of these solutions is more natural and i would like to know is bots are bonkers to tell me what solution is the proper way to do this.

the point here is not the chat service, it's more how to handle displaying input from one webpage user to display to all the users watching the same content.

Extra info:
Planing on using html/css/js on the client and php + sql on the server.

EDIT: I didn't want to start the discussion, basically i just wanted to know if solution 1 has performance problems, what those were and judging by the reply by griffin the problems start with 65k users when i have the refresh on every second, and that is acceptable for my scope.

Comment: You actually got the "problem" thing different than what I meant. You have a limit of 65536 ports, of which you can use 64511 (the first 0-1023 = 1024 ports are root only), and with persistent connections - e.g. websockets - you will run into this a lot sooner than with polling. It's not about performance - but don't worry about performance right now, better make sure to get your solution done correctly and working, and if you get perf. problems, you can probably gain more than enough by optimizing your db queries (use EXPLAIN, ADD INDEX, etc). Good luck in succeeding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, but I think you should pick Solution 1. Read on to find out why I think so.

**Solution 1** should probably be easier to implement, and if your server can handle more than 65k requests per second, you should use this, because otherwise you'd be hitting the port limit (assuming you only use one network device) before your load goes up.

**Solution 2** is probably harder to implement, also because you'd have to implement it atop of solution 1 because of race conditions, timeouts (client side at least, but depending on how much control you have over your server, server side as well). The upside is that if done correctly, it's possibly way more efficient than Solution 1, that is, until you hit the port limit (which you probably won't do anyway with your standard single server LAMP setup)

Regarding solution 2, you could also use websockets, which should prevent some of the problems (timeouts, if you do it right), and give you better performance, for the cost of crossbrowser problems.

As you say you'll be using php and some form of sql (you probably mean mysql I assume), use solution 1. As to why: As long as you use a scripting language made for the purpose of writing templates (look up the history of php), you shouldn't think about performance and the like too much, but about getting things done, and with regards to that, solution 1 is definitely simpler to implement without problems. Just make sure you use the correct database indexes and keep the overhead per request as low as possible (e.g. don't start a complete framework, but really only do 1 (my-)sql query)

Besides the already mentioned ones, you could also use chunked transfer as a substitution to Server Sent Events. There's some work to be done to get it working on different browsers, but it's also suitable for low latency communications. Other than that, it has the same downside regarding port limits as a websocket solution, as there's an always open connection between server and client.

Another possibility is to use a ready made chat application or even a chat service - there's tons of ready made solutions out there, some of which even employ their own webservers for better performance / features. For ready made solutions, you could have a look at Node.JS and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) (server side javascript), for chat as a service, it depends on your circumstances. Livechat for example provides chat service for client <-> support talks.

---

Before more people suggest Solution 2 while thinking of a sleep/query loop on the server:

The right way to implement Solution 2 would be to use inter- thread/process communication (IPC), which would really give you low latency and save resources. An example of these would be Semaphores, Mutexes or Condition Variables (sem_* and pthread_* functions). Otherwise you'd have the same lagginess and wasting of resources as Solution 1, with additional crossbrowser problems and more work to implement it cleanly. Also, in that case you probably should stop using some kind of sql based database and scripting language, and move to something with better performance (C, C++, Java - and nowadays even server side javascript outperforms php for these tasks, see the Socket.IO link above)

Comment: Your explanations on why not solution 2 with php are worth an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

First solution is wasting resources on both sides.
Take a look at [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/WebSockets) and [Server-Sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)
They are both quie new technologies, but gives you the best perfrmance of that kind of communication between browser and server.
Your second solution is sometimes used in production, because doesnt requires that users have only up to dated browsers.

Comment: I think you meant that the first solution is used if internet explorer is an issue (your usage of "second" is confusing in the last sentence)

Comment: Yes, IE is always an issue if we're talking about versions under 9.0.

Comment: I wasn't refering to IE with my comment, but your usage of "second" in your last sentence being confusing ("second" also means 2, and Solution 2 is the one with more crossbrowser issues)

Answer (score 0):

Soution 2 is better for two reasons:

1. It uses less resources on server (and client) side.
2. It is more responsive. The client will be immediatly informed of an event happening on the server, while in solution one, if you poll say every 30 seconds, the client can be notified with up to 30 seconds delay.

You have to determine a timeout, after wich the server will always reply. This assures that you don't loose the connection (or if the client looses connection, it will reconnect at the next timeout).

Example server side code:

```
$maxtime = 30; //sec
$wait = 1000; //msec
$startTime = microtime(true);
$result = false;
do {
    $result = query_datase_for_event(); // returns false if nothing happened
    if($result) break;
    usleep($wait * 1000);
} while (microtime(true) + ($wait / 1000) - $startTime < $maxtime);
echo json_encode($result);
```

I derived my client side code from [Realtime Ajax by Benjamin Hutchins](http://www.benhutchins.com/project/realtime-ajax).

Comment: (-1) You just mentioned more responsive and less resource wasting while using a sleep and querying the database in a loop. That's how NOT to do it, and the reason why I suggested Solution 1. A better way would be to use IPC like semaphores, mutexes, condition variables etc.

Comment: @griffin Yes there is a heavy solution using IPC and semaphores and all that. This would be the optimum. Solution 1 and 2 will make the same number of databse queries, but solution 2 will only make one connection instead of 30. So this is what I economize.  
And my code will still remain simple.

Comment: Which means you save - in the BEST case - up to 29 tcp connections over half a minute. I'd really like to see a single LAMP setup where this would make any difference - and while the OP hasn't said so, judging by his technology choices, he's most probably using such a LAMP setup. Also, even then your statement about more responsiveness is wrong, and you don't mention the downside of port limit. Btw even using mysql, there's something called triggers, which you could use to sys_exec() something(e.g. php script) and signal a new message. But then it gets complicated again, which is why ... u kno

Comment: Just to add: I'd normally also suggest using solution 2, but that's only if the OP wasn't explicitely stating that he's using php - after years of doing stuff like that myself with php for work, and recently building something alike with a C server, I think people using php should aim for stuff that works (=stuff THEY can build correctly), not for performance. I'd have removed the downvote by now for you taking up the work to provide a working example, but I can't unless you edit it :(